# Unable to fetch all records from LoginHistory?

Tags: rest-api, login-history

I was trying to fetch all records from LoginHistory and I got into strange problem. When I query salesforce with following query. It gives the complete result

```
SELECT Id, LoginTime FROM LoginHistory ORDER BY Id ASC
```

But, when I use the following query including **CountryIso** column. it gives the partial result starting from about 200th index.

```
SELECT Id, CountryIso,LoginTime FROM LoginHistory ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by partial results?

Comment: It skips the starting 200 rows.

Comment: Ya. I observed the same. countryIso varies the query result. Please check document about Login history